# Scrapy skipped some pages unexpectedly

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy crawler for iteratively 'next page' crawling.
my code is like this:

```
def parse(self, response):

    while self.current_page<=self.total_page:

        self.current_page = int(self.selector.css("something").extract()[-1])

        for post_node in self.selector.css("div.info-column"):
            yield {
                "location": post_node.css("something").extract(),
            }
        logging.info("************** now page is %d **************", self.current_page)
        logging.info("********** one page done,Going to next **********")

        try:

            self.next.send_keys('\n')
```

I expected the code to crawl the information of each page and then click next page. But the printed debug info shows that it skipped some pages very often.

what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apologies....I can't post a comment on your question yet as I don't have enough rep)
Please post more of your code...or the logs themselves.  There are so many points of divergence based on configuration we need more info to diagnose.  There is so much other code that might be interacting poorly here.

The self.current_page could definitely be stale/misleading when your logging.info statements are executed.  self is the spider object.  If any other code generates links that are processed by parse(), then your current_page will be stale/re-assigned when your logging statements are executed.

I notice your prints are after the yield:
yield pauses the function and resumes from that location after you try to iterate over it again.  Perhaps you are being misled due to your logging.info's happening way separate from the actual processing of the page.

The scrapy downloader queue is LIFO (Last In First Out).  So it will process "new" stuff before it gets back to trying to iterate on the 'first' parse() call.

I'm also guessing you are trying to operate on a AJAXy webpage where sending '\n' loads a new "page" under the hood?

What can be happening is that you load first page, set current_page, you yield new items, new items are processed, new links are farmed by other rules or mechanisms not shown, parse is called on those links, current_page is set to those new page numbers, ... bunch of other stuff..., finally your original parse() invocation is asked for it's next item,it resumes from yield statement and logs "now page is %d" with wildly wrong current_page number.

My answer is likely assuming things not necessarily true because of lack of info...but at least if gives you something to chew on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After hours of debugging. I finally get it work when I switch to xpath locator. When I read  their comment of the selector.css function. It was said that the css selector was translator into xpath. I am not really sure if it was due to the stability  of the css selector. But xpath works stably all the time for me.